# Does docker build ever automatically download updates to my base image?

Tags: docker

Suppose I have a Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN echo "Hello world"
```

If `debian:stable-slim` is not present on my local machine, `docker build` will automatically pull it from Docker Hub. But what about updates to that image? Will `docker build` perpetually continue to use the initial image download unless I delete it or include `--pull`?

Answer (score 0):

No it will not automatically update, not unless you tell it not to use the cache (or the cache gets invalidated in some other way).
So you will indeed keep using the initial image.

Comment: Does that mean that `--no-cache` implies `--pull`?